# Converting NVARCHAR to DateTime with Inconsistent Data (SQL Server 2014 Express)

Tags: sql, datetime, time, casting, sql-server-2014-express

Have a scenario where I need to convert a `NVARCHAR` column containing time in `hh:mm:ss` format to a `DateTime` column for better filtering.

One of the dilemmas is that I don't really have a date, and as far as I know SQL does not have a `Time` datatype, but I can convert all to '1900-01-01' and append the time portion - I'm fine with this, I will just use the '1900-00-00' during my comparison.

The bigger issue is that the time data I'm converting has hour values going up to 27 hrs (according to them there's more then 24 hrs in a day). So there are values ie: 24:17, 26:25, etc..

To convert to `datetime` I'd have to do a little cleansing/`string.replace` first ie: 24:17 -> 00:17; 02:25, etc.

But before I dive in to that, any other more elegant way of dealing with this in SQL?

Using SQL Server 2014 Express .

Comment: Which database are you referring to?

Comment: Depending on RDBMS, you may be able to simply update the data so that the first two digits are updated to the result of mod(24) then do your casting. Something like `SELECT MOD(substr(fieldName,1,2), 24);` but you may have to cast it first, so what RDBMS?

Comment: Starting with 2008, SQL Server does have a "Time" datatype.

Comment: Sry guys, completely forgot to mention which RDBMS. Just edited the question, suing Sql Express 2014.

Comment: **OF COURSE** SQL Server has a `TIME` datatype!! [Check out the relevant, freely available and Google-searchable MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) on that data type! That datatype was introduced way back in SQL Server **2008** - ages ago!

Comment: You really should sue SQL Express... :P

Comment: Well what do you know :) I was too used to SQL 2008 at work. Thanks for pointing this out!